# proftpd audit error

Tags: security, ftp, proftpd, tiger

I'm getting this warning in Tiger auditing reports

```
--WARN-- [lin003w] The process `proftpd' is listening on socket 21 (TCP on every interface) is run by proftpd.
```

The process is listening on port 21 OK
On every interface: I only have one OK
It's run by proftpd: that's the idea OK
I can't see the problem here...

Why do I get a warning about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning. On a security audit the software will try to warn you about all potential risks, even if it is a FTP that you know that is running. FTP is an insecure protocol and Tiger lists it. If you don't think it's a problem, then it's not :)

Comment: So it's not telling me the ftp server is misconfigured? it's only telling me I'm running it? If that's the case. How can I make Tiger stop stating the obvious?

Comment: Never used Tiger, but a quick look at its manpage shows some options to supress modules, maybe you can do that there. But even being obvious, it's cool for it to let you know what is going on, I would let it on and ignore it while reading the report.